# два конструктора ( один конструктор (без параметров ) должен вызывать второй конструктор (INT) )

Tags: java

public class MyInitTest {
    private String a;
    private double c;

```
{
    a = "non-static initialization block ";
    System.out.println(a);
}

{
    c = 20.03652;
    System.out.println(c + a);
}

static private String string;
static private int anInt;

static {
    string = "Static block";
    System.out.println(string);
}

static {
    anInt = 6;
    System.out.println(anInt + "Static block");
}
public MyInitTest(){

}
public MyInitTest(int){

}
введите сюда код
```

Comment: зачем вы создали дубликат вопроса?

Comment: тут я уже создал 2 конструктора чего оно подчеркивает первый?

Comment: Потому что вы неправильно объявили второй конструктор

Comment: Должно быть  `MyInitTest(int i)`, а не `MyInitTest(int)`

Comment: public MyInitTest() {

    }
    public  MyInitTest(int i){
        
    }
Получается этот процесс называется вызов 1го из  2гого?

Comment: нет, вызов в моем ответе в прошлом вопросе. у вас просто объявление двух конструкторов.